# What does "22 nm technology" refer to?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microprocessor

What exactly is it that's 22 nm?  Is it the thickness of the die?  The length of each transistor?  The length of wire between successive transistors?  I can't find any sources on the web that clarify this.

Comment: Where do you see "22 nm technology?"

Comment: right there on wikipedia, is wikipedia nor google available to you?

Comment: "I can't find any sources on the web that clarify this.": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_nanometer

Comment: took longer to read your question than it did to find the answer.

Comment: From the Wiki 7nm article: "The naming of process nodes by different major manufacturers (TSMC, Intel, Samsung, GlobalFoundries) is partially marketing driven and not directly related to any measurable distance on a chip"

Comment: I actually did search "22 nm" on DuckDuckGo.  All I found was a bunch of PR stuff from Intel about how their new 22 nm technology would revolutionize the industry.

Comment: It's the catch 22!

Comment: I work at a wafer (silicon) manufacturer. We deal in 2 and 10nm wafers. I have no idea what they're destined for.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc You are probably talking about overlay which is 2 nm (or less). Overlay is different than 22 nm 'pitch'.

Comment: web search skills  could be improved significantly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_nanometer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can easily find this answer by just Googling a bit and or reading a book about CMOS technology. You'd need to do that anyway to really understand what the "22nm" actually means.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think this is the right answer (or the best answer, till now). I don't think this question deserved to be closed, although it may have been formulated in a way that showed the OP *did* research the issue, but was confused by the mess the issue really is. Whenever marketing enters the engineering picture one has to be very careful to tell the science from the wankwords. ...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ... The question in itself has its merit simply because what a "process technology size" is is not really a clear-cut concept, and that is not obvious for a non-specialist, so it's worth to clarify the thing here on EE.SE. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

The 22nm is the minimum feature size of the Chip fabrication process. Usually it is the **minimum gate length** of the smallest size NMOS and PMOS transistors.

In the newest CMOS processes the actual minimum gate length might be slightly different, for example a 10 nm process might not have 10 nm gate length transistors.

In that case the "10 nm" is more a number related to the amount of **logic gates** which can be fitted on a certain size of silicon area. For 22 nm versus 10 nm, at 10 nm that density would be about (22/10)^2 = 4.8 times higher (squared since length and width should both scale). In reality that 4.8 is never reached due to many practical limitations.

Comment: If you voted to close the question, why did you answer it as well?

Comment: @W5VO I just like contradicting myself, it keeps me sharp ;-)